# Python Matplotlib scatter plot: specify color points depending on difference between X & Y:

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to color points uniquely **only if** there is a difference between the x & y values (e.g. abs(x - y) > 10).

How can I do that?

```
num = 1000
x = np.linspace(0,100, num = num)
y = np.random.normal(size = num)

plt.scatter(x, y, c='r', edgecolors='black')
plt.gca().spines['right'].set_color('none')
plt.gca().spines['top'].set_color('none')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a color vector based on the cut off rule such as

`plt.scatter(x, y, c=np.where(np.abs(x-y)>10, 'g', 'b'), edgecolors='black')`

[image]

Comment: What is there are multiple conditions - say to color red for values bigger than 10 and orange for colors bigger than 20 (values in a column of a data frame)